# Firefox right click menu is too long

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firebug

My Firefox is getting huge long menu when right click. I am searching on net. If you have any Idea, why it shows that type of menu, please help me.

Comment: sorry I forgot to add screenshot and now it doesn't show that much big. It was too big. with play, pause, mute etc, I guess it was full with all option they can put in menu. next time I will be more careful to ask a question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have got solution.

I just re-install my firebug.

Answer (score 1):

Go to help menu and select the option saying 'Restart with add-on's disabled'. After Firefox restarts then go to tools menu and select add-on's. Then you can disable/enable one add-on at a time and find the erroneous add-on.